# replace character randomly in words of list

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that puts "-" in given list randomly . just for privacy and for making it easier , i use a simple list here.but output is not my prefer answer.

example: if i enter "harddisk" ... output should be ha-dd-sk or -a-dd-sk or someyhing else

your help would be my appreciate.

```js
const words = ['harddisk', 'laptop'];
let count, i = 0;
let wordsLength = words[i].length;
let splitted = words[i].split('');
let incompleteWords = '';


function convertToIncomplete(words) {

  while (count < words[i].length / 2) {
    let incompleteWords = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsLength); //create new index

    return incompleteWords;
  }
}

let Words = prompt("enter your word : ");
//alert(convertToIncomplete(Words));
console.log(convertToIncomplete(Words));
```

this function just puts "-" randomly into a word that defined in given list

Comment: why do you define a const words and then a variable Words?

Comment: what do you mean? just for getting input.but when function runs , output is undefined

Comment: The `words` passed to `convertToIncomplete` from the prompt is a string not an array, so `words[i]` in the while condition will be a character (with length 1) (and always the first character because i is never changed). `count` is undefined and when `count < words[i].length / 2` is run for the while condition it gives false, so the while loop never runs and so the function returns undefined.

Comment: thank you @BenStephens for your useful hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    function convertToIncomplete(word){
    const numberOfDashes = Math.floor(Math.random()*(word.length));
        const places = [];
    
        while(places.length < numberOfDashes){
            const current = Math.floor(Math.random()*(word.length));
            if(places.includes(current)) continue;
            places.push(current);    
        }
    
        let newWord = word;
        for(let i=0;i<places.length;i++){
            newWord = newWord.substring(0, places[i])+'-'+newWord.substring(places[i]+1);
        }
        return newWord;
    }
    
    let Words = prompt("enter your word : ");
    //alert(convertToIncomplete(Words));
    console.log(convertToIncomplete(Words));
```

Comment: thank you so much .this is a perfect code and it is working .just one question: this code accept every word not from my list. can you give me a hand?@Alireza